# Socket bind() error: invalid operands to binary expression

Tags: c++, sockets, networking

Code:

```
 if (bind(sockfd, (sockaddr *) &addr, sizeof(addr)) == -1) {
```

Error:

```
fs_server.cpp:264:56: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('__bind<int &, sockaddr *,
      unsigned long>' and 'int')
    if (bind(sockfd, (sockaddr *) &addr, sizeof(addr)) == -1) {
```

This was working when I run this code using C++11, and also works when I run this code using C++ 17 on Linux. It does not work when I run it on Mac OS using C++17. To me, it looks like the error indicates that the comparison is between the function itself and -1. I'm not sure why this would happen. Am I interpreting something incorrectly?

Comment: Did you use `using namespace std;` in your source file?  If so, there is a  [std::bind](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind), and maybe you got bitten by the pitfalls of `using namespace std;`.

Comment: If you look at the error closely, the first argument is an `int&` and is a template argument.  The `bind` function is a `C`-based function, thus it does not take references and is not a template.  This is a clear indication that a different `bind` function is being called than the one you expected.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your code is trying to call the C++ `std::bind()` function, not the socket `bind()` function. This is likely due to a `using namespace std;` statement in your code.

To ensure the correct function is being called, you can either get rid of the `using` statement, or else qualify the call as using the function from the global namespace:

```cpp
if (::bind(sockfd, (sockaddr *) &addr, sizeof(addr)) == -1) {
```